# Python's newly featured numeric literal (eg; 234_432) doesn't work with .isdigit()?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I always understood that if something can be converted to integer (ie; something is string representation of numeric), isdigit() return True. This is not the case with the new feature. Here is the sample below:

[Code Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80YER.png)

But why?

Comment: `isdigit` does not mean "valid integer literal". [Read the docs.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit)

Comment: Which python version you are using ?

Comment: If you want to know whether you can call `int` on something, just call `int` on it.

Comment: Usually i don't use try except, but isdigit to check integers. Recently, these integers have been modified, in my project, to be in numeric literal form so that they don't look confusing and suddenly the project falls apart. That's why I asked why.

Is there isdigit equivalence that works in both cases?

Comment: I use 3.6, why?

Comment: I know it's not much of an answer but str.replace("_", "").isdigit() if you want to avoid a try-except would be an easy work around.

Comment: LOL, I guess then that's the closest option I can take to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: "Usually i don't use try except, but isdigit to check integers" - don't? You're using the wrong tool for the job. Hell, even '-1' returns false for isdigit. isdigit is not a check for whether a string represents an integer; isdigit is about digits.

Comment: to be honest, that never crossed my mind.

Comment: I don't think it should be considered a "feature".  It's just ugly.

Comment: It's definitely a subjective matter; personally I agree that it's uglier when it comes to smaller numbers, say if i did `x=4_50` but if I had a bigger number say `x=4_500_000_000` it'd be more readable than `x=4500000000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, looking at the python 3.6 [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) for the `isdigit` method.

> Return true if all characters in the string are digits and there is at least one character, false otherwise.

Since an underscore isn't a digit, the new format will not work well with the current implementation of `isdigit`. As I commented before, the immediate work around would be: `str.replace("_", "").isdigit()` where **str** is string containing the newly formatted number, while avoiding a try-except block with `int`.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to take out the negative sign for negative integers. This way negative integers will work as well. `str.replace("_", "").lstrip("-").isdigit()`.

Comment: And then you get True for '1-', or for '--1'.

Comment: I changed it to .strip which will help against --1 cases

Comment: This still gives True for '--1'.

Comment: It strips all of the negatives from the beggining

Comment: `--5` returns `5`, so `--5` is valid

Comment: It's a valid expression, but not a valid `int` argument. If we wanted to accept '--5', we'd want to accept stuff like '1+2'. In any case, you also return True for '_-2', which definitely isn't valid.